# Importing query results from another database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So I have two Access databases, let's call them myDatabase and anotherDatabase. In anotherDatabase there is a crosstab query. I want to get the results that this query produces into myDatabase without making ANY modifications to anotherDatabase or the query itself. I want myDatabase to be enitrely self-sufficient in the sense that the databases it interacts with will not have to be modified.

Could anyone give me advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Linked Table Manager to link the tables in `anotherDatabase` to `myDatabase`. Then you can have the query for `anotherDatabase` in `myDatabase` and just use that.

In the External Data tab (in `myDatabase`), click the button that says Import From Access. Except, instead of importing the table, click the radio button that says "Link to the data source by creating a linked table". Just follow the wizard and you should be all set.

You only need to link the tables that you require from your query. Another option would be to write some vba code in `myDatabase` that instantiates a connection to `anotherDatabase` and queries it, but I think that just linking the tables is a better solution with less hassle

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would link the tables together as you're suggesting but wouldn't that mean that data changed in the linked tables in myDatabase would also change in anotherDatabase? I would be afraid of accedential modifications.

How would I go about the second route of establishing a connection and querying?

Comment: If you want to do those gymnastics, then have a look at the second post http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=156716

Answer (score 2):

Linking external tables is limited to external *tables* and won't allow you to get data from *queries* in another db.
One solution for external queries is to create a local query using the IN predicate:

```
SELECT * FROM myQuery IN 'c:\test\otherdb.mdb'
```